# SoundTrap 4300 CH1 Faint Signal & Banding

Tags: recording, soundtrap, hydrophone, equipment, hardware

We have collected 2 channeled recordings from two different ST4300 units, and more recently we have noticed that the signal in CH1 looks really weak. This has occurred in most but not all new deployments. We know the signal is there because if we make an LTSA from the recordings we can see dolphins and ship noise, albeit very faint. What we don’t understand is that when we decimate the recordings to 12kHz from 384kHz we get a very odd banding pattern in the signal. It almost looks like the signal is cutting in and out.

**Has anyone experienced this faint signal and banding before with a SoundTrap 4300 model? We aren’t sure why this is happening.**

[image: Both channel waveforms and spectrogram, showing faint signal on CH1]
***Both channel waveforms and spectrograms, showing faint signal on CH1***

[image]
***Banding in 12kHz decimated wav files***

Comment: Can you tell us, how you decimate?

Comment: We decimated using the Triton package in MATLAB

Comment: Sorry, but which  function call, how many steps, what decimation factors? It is difficult with the given information to help.

Comment: @WMXZ the lab uses SIO's Triton 2020 to decimate using the "decimate all wav files in a folder" option from the menu drop down. We decimate by a factor of 32. We don't get to chose the step size as it is built into the code from what I believe. We have used this function on over 50 deployments with out a prior issue so I don't think it is related to the software?

Comment: This looks like a weak connection to me. Have you tested this on shore with different hydrophones in different ports? I feel like your decimation is weird because your signal isn't complete for its sample rate.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer concerning decimation:

according to matlab : "Decimation factor, specified as a positive integer. For better results when r is greater than 13, divide r into smaller factors and call decimate several times."

So, I would suggest to try to decimate 4 times each decimation by a factor of 8, to see if result improves.

Reason, why high decimation factors are problematic is the required anti-aliasing filter: in the case of OP, the LP cutoff frequency is 1/32 = 0.031, which is very low and may result into a weird filters responses, as Triton does not specify a filter order.